# MSc in mathematics from MChem?

Tags: graduate-admissions, mathematics, changing-fields

I was wondering is it possible to study an MSc in applied mathematics with a background of a masters in chemistry? I have an absolute passion for mathematics and would love the opportunity to study a single year masters.

Would I be given the opportunity to take the entrance exams without formal training? Or would I be discounted instantly?

I have read extensively into the content of the course I have in mind including looking at all their past papers.

I understand it is going to be an individual basis depending on the university and my grades but wanted to hear has someone done or heard of anything similar?

Comment: In what country were you thinking of applying? In the US, graduate programs typically do not have entrance exams. Admissions are decided mainly on the basis of grades and recommendations. There is the GRE, but it usually has only a minor effect on the admission decision. So if you don't have prior coursework preparing you for the program, you won't be admitted.

Comment: @NateEldredge I am looking at a course in the UK, and it does have an admissions exam to the programme, my main question is would they allow me to sit the entrance exam, would there be any scope for admission if I were to do alright on it, or is it a discipline that people can (albeit rarely) switch into. The course is rather involved, but I am well aware of its content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just from a quick look at a few applied MSc programs, there are a number of classes that would be difficult to complete without serious background in mathematics: classes like partial differential equations, applied algebra, probability theory and combinatorial algorithms were a few that showed up in most that I doubt you could manage without rigorous undergraduate preparation. However, if you have taken classes to prepare you for this (like a minor as an undergraduate), or the MSc you have in mind is less rigorous, or you are willing to devote a year or so to prepare on your own, I fail to see why they would refuse you to take the entrance exam. At least in the US, a good subject score on the math GREs would show the university that while you have a less traditional background, you can still do well in the program.

Basically, it comes down to how mathematically rigorous the program is and how strong your math background is. Liking math is unfortunately not enough to pass a class on PDEs. You would probably need to provide some evidence in your application that you have a sufficient math background, and taking a standardized exam with a good score, even if it is not required in the country you are applying, would be one way to do so.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, you have given me a lot to think about and encouragement for the future! :)

Comment: @RedPen I'm in grad school doing a PhD in math myself, so I think it's a great choice, as long as you have the necessary background :)

Answer (score 1):

My experience is that students with bachelors degrees in the physical sciences and engineering often work out well in our graduate program in applied mathematics.  The key factor is that students need to have at least the equivalent of a strong minor in mathematics (including undergraduate courses in ordinary and partial differential equations, vector calculus, probability and statistics, linear algebra, and analysis.)  Students in math intensive majors like physics and electrical engineering often take many of these courses anyway, so the additional course work required to be prepared for graduate study in applied mathematics may not be that much.

If you don't have this undergraduate mathematics background, then you will probably have to take some or all of these courses before you can be admitted into a graduate program.